# Configure Project / Clean to delete temp files

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to configure the clean functionality of eclipse?

For example that all *.sqlite files are deleted if i execute the function.

This is necessary in my project cause i haver diverent temp outputs like csv or sqlite files. And it is anojing to delete them all by hand.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is by create a `batch file` located
For example in your desktop contains some thing like that :

```
del C:\blablabla\yourprojectBath\*.svc 
del C:\blablabla\yourprojectBath\*.sqlite
```

Answer (score 0):

The clean functionality of Eclipse is limited to cached information and metadata associated with a project. It does not delete free form files.

The only solutions that I can recommend are:

1. Have your code clean up previously generate files
2. Use a solution as presented by Ahmed above.
3. Make use of Ant functionality inside of Eclipse. Create an ant
   build.xml file with a clean target.  Then click once on the file to highlight it and right click->Run As->Clean.  The menu should show you the
   different targets you can run.